# BB10: Tackle input in background

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-10

I have app requirement to handle either power button, volume button or any other input while app is in either background or foreground or phone is in sleep etc. ?

Does BB 10 allow automatically starting app in background once phone restarts etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [trigger for headless applications](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/triggers.html#triggerforwhenthedevicestarts) (short and long running) that will lauch the application on system start.

Volume and power button events may be available through BPS, but don't know for sure.

Comment: is trigger possible in android port for BB 10?

Comment: Just to confirm, if you are doing an Android port, I am not aware of a way of doing this.  If you are writing a native app, then I can confirm that the volume and power buttons are available through BPS.